# Connecting to a Qt signal in a derived class

Tags: c++, qt, box2d

I'm building a physics sandbox based upon Box2D and using Qt for the UI. I have a derived class of QGraphicsScene (**Box2DView**) that handles mouse and keyboard events. I would like to connect to the **sceneRectChanged** signal (`void QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged ( const QRectF & rect ) [signal]`), but I don't know how to reference it given that my instance is of the derived class.

I've tried to connect it as follows:

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(sceneRectChanged( const QRectF & )),
        this, SLOT(debugViewChanged()) );
```

where `view` is an instance of the Box2DView. I get the following runtime error:

> Object::connect: No such signal Box2DView::sceneRectChanged( const QRectF & )

However, when I try to override setRectChanged in Box2DView, as follows:

```
void Box2DView::sceneRectChanged () {
  QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged ( this->rect() );
}
```

I get the compile-time error

> cannot call member function ‘void QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged(const QRectF&)’ without object

I know that my override method isn't right, but can't figure out what to do. Is there a different syntax to reference a base class's Qt signal?

**EDIT:** The solution appeared in the comments to the question. I was confusing the Scene and the View. My Box2DView class is indeed derived from QGraphicsView, so the solution was to change the connection to reference `view->scene()` for the signal.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Box2DView is a subclass of QGraphicsScene? Connecting a parent's signal is perfectly valid in Qt (for example, connecting readyRead() for any QIODevice subclass works fine), although I can imagine a few possible reasons for it to not work properly. But your second issue makes me even more suspicious - your sceneRectChanged() override doesn't make much sense from the Qt point of view, but the compiler shouldn't care - signals are protected, so it should allow access to them.

Comment: Are you sure that your Box2DView class is a subclass of QGraphicsScene, and not a subclass of QGraphicsView?  If Box2DView is actually a subclass of QGraphicsView, that would probably explain the problems.

Comment: A sudden thought occurred to me: could it be that you forgot to specify public inheritance? That could explain why the compiler doesn't see the parent methods.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: that was the issue exactly. I was confusing QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene (been staring at the code too long, I guess). Changing the signal connection to `connect(view->scene(), SIGNAL(sceneRectChanged( const QRectF & )), this, SLOT(debugViewChanged( const QRectF & )) );` fixed this problem (I had to also give the slot the same argument).

Comment: @clebio, you don't have to give the slot all the arguments if you don't need to use them. Your previous slot (with no arguments) would work just as fine. The first arguments of the slot must match those of the signal, but there may be less argument, the rest will just be ignored.

Comment: it's a good idea to suffix `QGraphicsScene` derived classes with `Scene`, and `QGraphicsView` derived classes with 'View', ex: `class MyView: public QGraphicsView`, `class MyScene: public QGraphicsScene`. This would have allowed you to avoid this confusion

Comment: @ak, well, his Box2DView turned out to be a derived class of QGraphicsView, so it's okay name-wise. It's just that even good names don't make you a 100% error-free superhuman.

Comment: In my opinion this code is correct. But i have 2 question for You: - Has Your derivate Q_OBJECT ? - Have You re-run qmake ?